FactualCorrectness in RAGAS metric giving error as scoring, PromptValue has no len()
I am following this document https://docs.ragas.io/en/latest/concepts/metrics/available_metrics/factual_correctness/#example
Ragas version:0.2.6
Python version: 3.12.3
I have looked into this issue, but its not resolved:  https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/issues/576
from langchain_openai.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain_openai.embeddings import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

azure_model=AzureChatOpenAI(
                api_version=config.pf_api_version,
                azure_endpoint=config.pf_oa_endpoint,
                azure_ad_token=token,
                max_tokens=config.max_tokens,
                model=config.pf_llm_deployment,
    
            )

azure_embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
    openai_api_version=config.pf_api_version,
    azure_endpoint=config.pf_oa_endpoint_embed,
    azure_ad_token=token,
    model=config.pf_embedding_engine,
)


from ragas.dataset_schema import SingleTurnSample
from ragas.metrics._factual_correctness import FactualCorrectness

sample = SingleTurnSample(
    response="The Eiffel Tower is located in Paris.",
    reference="The Eiffel Tower is located in Paris. I has a height of 1000ft."
)

scorer = FactualCorrectness()

scorer.llm = azure_model
scorer.embeddings=azure_embeddings
await scorer.single_turn_ascore(sample)

Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 18
16 scorer.llm = azure_model
17 scorer.embeddings=azure_embeddings
---> 18 await scorer.single_turn_score(sample)
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/metrics/base.py:285, in SingleTurnMetric.single_turn_score(self, sample, callbacks)
283     if not group_cm.ended:
284         rm.on_chain_error(e)
--> 285     raise e
286 else:
287     if not group_cm.ended:
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/metrics/base.py:279, in SingleTurnMetric.single_turn_score(self, sample, callbacks)
275             raise ImportError(
276                 "It seems like your running this in a jupyter-like environment. Please install nest_asyncio with pip install nest_asyncio to make it work."
277             )
278     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
--> 279     score = loop.run_until_complete(
280         self._single_turn_ascore(sample=sample, callbacks=group_cm)
281     )
282 except Exception as e:
283     if not group_cm.ended:
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py:98, in _patch_loop..run_until_complete(self, future)
95 if not f.done():
96     raise RuntimeError(
97         'Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
---> 98 return f.result()
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/futures.py:203, in Future.result(self)
201 self.__log_traceback = False
202 if self._exception is not None:
--> 203     raise self._exception.with_traceback(self._exception_tb)
204 return self._result
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py:314, in Task.__step_run_and_handle_result(failed resolving arguments)
310 try:
311     if exc is None:
312         # We use the send method directly, because coroutines
313         # don't have __iter__ and __next__ methods.
--> 314         result = coro.send(None)
315     else:
316         result = coro.throw(exc)
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/metrics/_factual_correctness.py:279, in FactualCorrectness._single_turn_ascore(self, sample, callbacks)
276 assert reference is not None, "Reference is not set"
277 assert response is not None, "Response is not set"
--> 279 response_claims = await self.decompose_claims(response, callbacks)
280 reference_response = await self.verify_claims(
281     premise=reference, hypothesis_list=response_claims, callbacks=callbacks
282 )
284 if self.mode != "precision":
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/metrics/_factual_correctness.py:252, in FactualCorrectness.decompose_claims(self, response, callbacks)
250 assert isinstance(sentences, list), "Segmenter must return a list of sentences"
251 prompt_input = ClaimDecompositionInput(response=response, sentences=sentences)
--> 252 result = await self.claim_decomposition_prompt.generate(
253     data=prompt_input, llm=self.llm, callbacks=callbacks
254 )
255 claims_list = [
256     claim for claim_list in result.decomposed_claims for claim in claim_list
257 ]
258 return claims_list
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/prompt/pydantic_prompt.py:125, in PydanticPrompt.generate(self, llm, data, temperature, stop, callbacks, retries_left)
122 callbacks = callbacks or []
124 # this is just a special case of generate_multiple
--> 125 output_single = await self.generate_multiple(
126     llm=llm,
127     data=data,
128     n=1,
129     temperature=temperature,
130     stop=stop,
131     callbacks=callbacks,
132     retries_left=retries_left,
133 )
134 return output_single[0]
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/ragas/prompt/pydantic_prompt.py:185, in PydanticPrompt.generate_multiple(self, llm, data, n, temperature, stop, callbacks, retries_left)
178 prompt_rm, prompt_cb = new_group(
179     name=self.name,
180     inputs={"data": processed_data},
181     callbacks=callbacks,
182     metadata={"type": ChainType.RAGAS_PROMPT},
183 )
184 prompt_value = PromptValue(text=self.to_string(processed_data))
--> 185 resp = await llm.generate(
186     prompt_value,
187     n=n,
188     temperature=temperature,
189     stop=stop,
190     callbacks=prompt_cb,
191 )
193 output_models = []
194 parser = RagasOutputParser(pydantic_object=self.output_model)
File ~/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/chat_models.py:627, in BaseChatModel.generate(self, messages, stop, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, run_id, **kwargs)
606 inheritable_metadata = {
607     **(metadata or {}),
608     **self._get_ls_params(stop=stop, **kwargs),
609 }
611 callback_manager = CallbackManager.configure(
612     callbacks,
613     self.callbacks,
(...)
618     self.metadata,
619 )
620 run_managers = callback_manager.on_chat_model_start(
621     self._serialized,
622     messages,
623     invocation_params=params,
624     options=options,
625     name=run_name,
626     run_id=run_id,
--> 627     batch_size=len(messages),
628 )
629 results = []
630 for i, m in enumerate(messages):
TypeError: object of type 'StringPromptValue' has no len()
Either RAGAS in not formatting SingleTurnSample into format the langchain requires?

Done, please check now!
